# Espressioni dialettali toscane sul prestare denaro

Tags: regional, history

In una commedia settecentesca (Giovan Battista Fagiuoli, "Non bisogna in amor correre a furia") ho trovato l'espressione "a crocchio, a barbocchio, a triangolo" riferita al prestito di denaro, ma in nessun dizionario o raccolta ho trovato riferimenti o altre occorrenze che spieghino questo uso. Qualcuno ha suggerimenti in proposito?
Grazie mille

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Probabilmente non cambia molto, ma potresti inserire il titolo e l'autore della commedia settecentesca? Aiuterebbe come minimo a capirne le origini.

Comment: In effetti, visto che neppure il GDLI registra questo uso di “barbocchio” (https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/2?seq=69), sembra proprio un'espressione dialettale o un'invenzione dell'autore della commedia.

Comment: In dialetto pratese barbocchio, significa anche  (Ragazzo ingenuo e sprovveduto)
 https://www.iltirreno.it/prato/cronaca/2014/02/21/news/vocabolario-pratese-italiano-lettera-b-1.8713050

Comment: Grazie mille. Sarebbe interessante capire se in dialetto pratese esistono riferimenti anche agli altri termini. In particolare "a triangolo" mi sembra difficile da comprendere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sulla pagina 609 dell'Ottocentesco [*Nuovo elenco di voci e maniere di dire biasimate e di altre che sembrano di buona ragione e mancano ne' vocabolarj italiani*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_idB3wF_9TM8C/page/608/mode/2up), compilato da Lorenzo Molossi, si trovano informazioni su quelle che sembrano essere state pratiche degli usurai:

> I termini  principali  dell'arte degli  usurieri  sono:
> lo  *Scrocchio*, il  *Barocchio*, la  *Ritràngola*  o il  *Ritràngolo*, il  *Lecco-fermo*, lo *Scrocchio-dotato*, e il  *Babbomorto*. 
>      1.°  Lo  *Scrocchio* è quel
> contratto  in  cui  si  vendono a tempo  robe  o mercanzie per  assai  più  che  le  non  vagliano. Colui  che  le  dà  si dice:  *Scrocchiante attivo*,
> e colui  che  le  piglia: *Scrocchiante passivo*. Il  primo  si dice  che  *dà  lo  scrocchio*,
> o che  *scrocchia*, o, se  faccia questo bel  mestiere  abitualmente, che  *dà  a scrocchio*: l'altro  *piglia  lo  scrocchio*. 
>      
> 2.°  *Barocchio*  si  domanda la  vendita  a rotta  della roba  avuta  *a scrocchio*.
>
>      
> 3.°  La  *Ritràngola*  si  fa quando  quegli  che  ha  venduto la  roba  la  ricompera per  pochissimo  danaro:  e questo  negozietto  si  chiama anco: *a mangia  mezzo*.

Comment: Grazie mille. Queste indicazioni sono davvero molto utili